# How do I style primeng p-dropdown & p-chips inside a p-confirmDialog dialog?

Tags: css, angular, primeng

How do I go about styling primeng **p-dropdown** & **p-chips** in a **p-confirmDialog** as mentioned in the subject line?

I'm using **primeng 15.x** and **angular 15.x**.

I've successfully managed to style pInputText controls using the 'class' attribute but cannot seem to style the p-dropdown & p-chips using the 'class' or the 'styleClass' attribute.

Below are some snippets of my code:

app-modal.component.html

```
<p-confirmDialog [style]="{width: '50vw'}" [baseZIndex]="10000"></p-confirmDialog>

<div class="app-modal">
    ...

    <app-dropdown class="element inputtext" label="Form" [options]="data" optionLabel="value" id="id" name="select"
        optionValue="key" [model]="data" propertyName="key" [required]="true" [showClear]="true">
    </app-dropdown>

    <p-chips styleClass="element inputtext" id="frequency" name="frequency" label="frequency" [(ngModel)]="capturedFrequencies" separator=","></p-chips>

    ...
</div>
```

app-modal.component.scss

```
.element {
    border: none !important;
}

.inputtext {
    background: rgb(255 255 255 / 60%) no-repeat;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1565C0, #1565C0), linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38));
    background-size: 0 2px, 100% 1px;
    background-position: 50% 100%, 50% 100%;
    background-origin: border-box;
}

.inputtext:enabled:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: rgb(255 255 255 / 60%);
    border-color: transparent;
    background-size: 100% 2px, 100% 1px;
}

.inputtext:enabled:hover {
    background-color: rgb(255 255 255 / 60%);
    border-color: transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1565C0, #1565C0), linear-gradient(to 
    bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you try using the classes from the docs for [p-chips](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v15-lts/chips#style) and [p-dropdown](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v15-lts/dropdown#style) to configure these element's style instead of the `styleClass` attribute.

Also, as a rule of thumb we need to avoid the `class` attribute when using primeNg elements because the runtime HTML code is usually not as simple as what is in the template, for example this (from [primeng's example](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v15-lts/dropdown#basic)):

```
<p-dropdown [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" optionLabel="name"></p-dropdown>
```

becomes this:

```
<p-dropdown optionlabel="name" class="p-element p-inputwrapper p-inputwrapper-filled ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty">
  <div class="p-dropdown p-component">
    <div class="p-hidden-accessible"><input type="text" readonly="" aria-haspopup="listbox" pautofocus=""
                                            role="combobox" class="p-element" aria-expanded="false"></div>
    <span class="p-element p-dropdown-label p-inputtext ng-star-inserted" id="pr_id_6_label">New York<!----><!---->
      <!----></span><!----><!----><!----><!---->
    <div role="button" aria-label="dropdown trigger" aria-haspopup="listbox" class="p-dropdown-trigger"><!---->
      <chevrondownicon class="p-element p-icon-wrapper ng-star-inserted">
        <svg width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 14 14" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
             class="p-dropdown-trigger-icon p-icon" aria-hidden="true">
          <path
            d="M7.01744 10.398C6.91269 10.3985 6.8089 10.378 6.71215 10.3379C6.61541 10.2977 6.52766 10.2386 6.45405 10.1641L1.13907 4.84913C1.03306 4.69404 0.985221 4.5065 1.00399 4.31958C1.02276 4.13266 1.10693 3.95838 1.24166 3.82747C1.37639 3.69655 1.55301 3.61742 1.74039 3.60402C1.92777 3.59062 2.11386 3.64382 2.26584 3.75424L7.01744 8.47394L11.769 3.75424C11.9189 3.65709 12.097 3.61306 12.2748 3.62921C12.4527 3.64535 12.6199 3.72073 12.7498 3.84328C12.8797 3.96582 12.9647 4.12842 12.9912 4.30502C13.0177 4.48162 12.9841 4.662 12.8958 4.81724L7.58083 10.1322C7.50996 10.2125 7.42344 10.2775 7.32656 10.3232C7.22968 10.3689 7.12449 10.3944 7.01744 10.398Z"
            fill="currentColor"></path>
        </svg>
      </chevrondownicon><!----><!----><!----><!----></div>
    <p-overlay class="p-element ng-tns-c33-6 ng-star-inserted"><!----></p-overlay>
  </div>
</p-dropdown>
```

You will need to have few iterations with changing styles on these exposed classes from the docs and/or adding the attributes styleClass / panelStyleClass / tooltipStyleClass to see which will be placed on the part of the element you want to style.

Comment: apologies for the late reply, I appreciate your response on my question raised.